# Is inplace ==False creates copy or reference the same data set?

Tags: python, dataset

As we know

```
if inplace is False
      Assign to a new variable;
 else
      No need to assign
```

in case of `inplace== false`
is the variable is the copy or has the reference which point the same data set?

Comment: Hey @desertnaut
First of all sorry for this wrong tag 
i have just started learning this technology so i am very confused with all these things.

Answer (score 0):

It is a copy. You can try:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6]})
>>> df2 = df.drop('b', axis=1, inplace=False)

>>> df2
   a
0  1
1  2
2  3

>>> df
   a  b
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
```

Answer (score 0):

When `in_place = True` data is renamed in the original place.

Whereas

if you use `in_place = False`, a copy of the data is returned after performing your desired operations.